# Reflection API missing in Portable Class Library Profile259

Tags: c#, reflection, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I had the following code working fine in a PCL with TargetFrameworkVersion of 4.0 and TargetFrameworkProfile of Profile104.

```
 public class AppCapabilitiesRepository : IAppCapabilityRepository
    {
        private readonly Type _typeOfAppCapability = typeof (IAppCapability);

        public IList<IAppCapability> GetCapabilities()
        {
            var capabilities = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(IsAppCapability).ToArray();
            var viewModels = capabilities.Select(capability => ((IAppCapability)Activator.CreateInstance(capability)))
                .Where(c => c.IsActive)
                .OrderBy(c => c.Popularity).ToList();
            return viewModels;
        }

        private bool IsAppCapability(Type type)
        {
            return _typeOfAppCapability.IsAssignableFrom(type) && !type.IsAbstract && !type.IsInterface;
        }
    }
```

After upgrading the project to TargetFrameworkVersion of 4.5 and TargetFrameworkProfile of Profile259, these reflection APIs no longer can be found:

**Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly, Type.IsAbstract and Type.IsInterface.**

This solution is also using MvvmCross 3.5.1 if this matters.

What do I do now?

Comment: If you're updating from .net 4 to .net 4.5, then you need to update your Reflection code to match the Microsoft changes - read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/08/28/evolving-the-reflection-api.aspx for more info (it's pretty quick)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Stuart for the tip. API changes I needed to do are as follows:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly => this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly
Type.IsAbstract => TypeInfo.IsAbstract where TypeInfo.GetTypeInfo()
Type.IsInterface => TypeInfo.IsInterface where TypeInfo = Type.GetTypeInfo()
```

Modified code is as follows:

```
  public class AppCapabilitiesRepository : IAppCapabilityRepository
    {
        private readonly Type _typeOfAppCapability = typeof (IAppCapability);

        public IList<IAppCapability> GetCapabilities()
        {
            var capabilities =  GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetTypes().Where(IsAppCapability).ToArray();
            var viewModels = capabilities.Select(capability => ((IAppCapability)Activator.CreateInstance(capability)))
                .Where(c => c.IsActive)
                .OrderBy(c => c.Popularity).ToList();
            return viewModels;
        }

        private bool IsAppCapability(Type type)
        {
            var typeInfo = type.GetTypeInfo();
            return _typeOfAppCapability.IsAssignableFrom(type) && !typeInfo.IsAbstract && !typeInfo.IsInterface;
        }
    }
```

Some laws are being violated here but .....

Hope this helps others.